# router.navigate test TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined

Tags: angular, unit-testing, routes, karma-jasmine

I am trying to create just simple test for method that contains **router.navigate** inside, unfortunately I think that I should have RouterTestingModule in my imports. Because of that i am importing RouterTestingModule and in providers I also have Router to spy on navigate. With that I got this error which might be because of overriding routers.

The method in component

```
onUserInfo() {
    this.router.navigate(['student/info']);
  }
```

and spec file is:

```
fdescribe('NavbarComponent', () => {
    let component: NavbarComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavbarComponent>;
    let appStore: Store<fromApp.State>
    const fakeUser = { username: '', password: '', role: 'PARENT' }
    let mockRouter;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        mockRouter = {
            navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate')
          }

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                RouterTestingModule,
                SharedModule,
                AuthModule,
                MaterialModule,
                StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
                EffectsModule.forRoot([AuthEffects, UserEffects])
            ],
            declarations: [
                AppComponent,
                WelcomeComponent,
                NavbarComponent,
                ProjectInfoComponent
            ],
            providers: [
                { provide: Router, useValue: mockRouter},

            ]
        }).compileComponents();

        appStore = TestBed.get(Store);
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavbarComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });
 it('test', fakeAsync(()=> {
        fixture.detectChanges();

        component.onUserInfo();
          expect(mockRouter.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['student/info']);

    }))
```

Can someone gave me a hint on this issue? 
When I delete RouterTestingModule I got

```
'router-outlet' is not a known element:
```

when I delete { provide: Router, useValue: mockRouter} I will get

```
Expected spy navigate to have been called with [ [ 'student/info' ] ] but it was never called.
```

Is there any workaround?  Thanks in advance.

**EDIT (SOLUTION)**

```
fdescribe('NavbarComponent', () => {
    let component: NavbarComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<NavbarComponent>;
    let appStore: Store<fromApp.State>
    const fakeUser = { username: '', password: '', role: 'PARENT' }
    let router: Router

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes),
                SharedModule,
                AuthModule,
                MaterialModule,
                StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
                EffectsModule.forRoot([AuthEffects, UserEffects])
            ],
            declarations: [
                AppComponent,
                WelcomeComponent,
                NavbarComponent,
                ProjectInfoComponent
            ],
            providers: [
            ]
        }).compileComponents();

        appStore = TestBed.get(Store);
        router = TestBed.get(Router)

    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavbarComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });


    it('asd', fakeAsync(()=> {
        fixture.detectChanges();

        let navigateSpy = spyOn(router, 'navigate');
        component.onUserInfo();
        expect(navigateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['student/info']);

    }))
});
```